# A simple WPF trigger not works

Tags: wpf, triggers

I'm trying to set the width property of textbox when text is "ABC",however the trigger doesn't work. the width remains '40'.

```
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="295,211,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40"  Text="{Binding Text}"  >
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="ABC" >
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```

Comment: Is that your actual XAML? You wrote `"width "` instead of `"Width"`...

Comment: updated,It's 'Width'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `Width` property in the `TextBox` definition because this will take precedence over the `Trigger`. Set the Width in a `Style` setter as below:

```
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="295,211,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Text="{Binding Text}"  >
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="40"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="ABC" >
                        <Setter Property="Width " Value="120"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

**UPDATE -**

Local value has higher precedence compared to triggers. Refer to this - [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

Comment: so,the triggers can not modify the property listed in the definition?

Comment: Properties that are set in the definition will override properties set in a Style (including Triggers). When you need a default value you need to define it in the Style as above and not in the element declaration.